Problema con compatibilidad de Tablets "Tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta version" en Google Play
he estado haciendo pruebas para una app pero al probarla en tablets me dice "Tu dispositivo no es compatible con esta versión".
¿Qué ya he intentado?
-Bajar la version de minSdkVersion a 21, sí me da más dispositivos pero al que tengo no
(Lenovo Tab-X304F, Android: 8.1.0)
-Agregar:
'''
implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.1.0-alpha04'
'''

-Volver a subir el minsdk porque en google play console me marcaba un error, y leí que esto podría afectar a la funcionalidad de ciertas librerias.
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 34    
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'

-Agregar user-features (sin éxito) y agregar android:required="false"
Mis archivos:
AndroidManifest:
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" android:required="false"/>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" android:required="false"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" android:required="false"/>

<!--  hardware no requeridas -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
    
    <application
        android:label="Example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:allowBackup="false">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
        <!-- SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- inAppBrowserView launch mode support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

build.gradle:
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.example"
    compileSdk 34
    //ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile = keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword = keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
      coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
      implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.1.0-alpha04'
}

pubspec.yaml:
environment:
  sdk: ^3.3.0
# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sticky_headers: ^ 0.3.0+2
  shared_preferences:  ^2.0.15
  # async: ^2.9.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  http: ^1.2.1
  sqflite: any
  path: any
  path_provider: ^2.0.10
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences_android: ^2.2.1
  avatar_glow: ^3.0.1
  speech_to_text: ^6.6.2
  lottie: ^3.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  local_auth: ^2.2.0
  local_auth_android: ^1.0.37
  async: ^2.11.0
  flutter_device_type: ^0.4.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  flutter_speed_dial: ^7.0.0
  table_calendar: ^3.1.0
  floating_action_bubble_custom: ^1.0.0+2
  flutter_localization: ^0.2.0
  flutter_rounded_date_picker: ^3.0.4
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  timeago: ^3.6.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0
  modal_progress_hud_nsn: ^0.5.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  awesome_dialog: ^3.2.1
  flutter_slidable: ^3.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.0
  rxdart: ^0.28.0
  timezone: ^0.9.4
  numberpicker: ^2.1.2
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.19.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
